# HTML form looking differently on Chrome 24 than it used to on Chrome 23

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, css-tables

I have notices that **my website looks different since the last update of Chrome** (24.0.1312.56) **although I don't have modified any line of code.** More precisely, inputs on a form are localized at different place and the text seems bigger than before.

[Here's the rendering on Chrome 23](http://i48.tinypic.com/145o5e.jpg)
[And here's the rendering on the latest version of Chrome.](http://i50.tinypic.com/11qprep.jpg)

I make the test on different computers and the result is the same.
Nothing has changed on IE and Firefox.

Please see the incriminated code below.

**HTML**

```
<table class="form-fields-table form-main-block">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="form-select-col"></col>
    <col class="form-select-col"></col>
    <col class="form-select-col"></col>
  </colgroup>
  <tr class="form-input-block">
    <td class="form-label">
      <label for="sit_pro">Vous êtes<span class="form-required">*</span> :</label>
      <select name="sit_pro">
        <option value="0">-- Sélectionnez --</option>
        (...)
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="form-label">
      <label for="sit_bien">Votre situation<span class="form-required">*</span>:</label>
      <select name="sit_bien">
        <option value="0">-- Sélectionnez --</option>
        (...)
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="form-label">
      <label for="type_bien">Votre type de bien<span class="form-required">*</span> : </label>
      <select name="type_bien">
        <option value="0">-- Sélectionnez --</option>
        (...)
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-fields-table .form-main-block td {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.form-fields-table td {
  border-spacing: 10px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

.form-comments-table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.form-fields-table td.form-label-top {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.form-select-col {
  width: 200px;
}

.form-label {
  text-align: left;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to the internet. It's a fact of web development that browsers often change the way they behave when they upgrade.

Comment: You're using a table to size them. Using explicit sizes with table elements is more of a friendly hint than a precise setting because of the other constraints that apply during table rendering.

Comment: If you want to avoid the labels breaking awkwardly, I'd try using `white-space: pre-wrap` on them instead, and making the dropdown lists  span the width of the cell. And/or make the columns wide enough to leave some wiggle space. I'd also try setting the widths on the table cells, or using `min-width` as well as `width`. (I had the same requirement and ended up just doing all of the above and crossing my fingers, not sure what exactly made the dimension stick.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Google Chrome sets the width of the column according to the largest input text. In my case, the largest input text is one of the select input's option of the middle dropdown list.

I've fixed the problem using the `max-width` property both on `td` and `select` tags:

```
.form-label {
  text-align: left;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width: 155px; // new
}

.form-label select {
    max-width: 155px; // new
}
```

And the rendering is just fine.